Allowing access to an API from specific address in istio GKE mesh
This is Istio GKE service mesh
I want to allow access to an api in a service in istio from a specific IP address. I have added the ip address in service istio authorization file as an rule. After adding this, now I am able to access the API via postman from any network.  The configuration not working as expected? Ideally the api should be allowed to access from the mentioned IP address only
Istio authorization:
action: ALLOW
  rules:
    - from:
      - source: 
          remoteIpBlocks: [IP address]
  rules:
    - to:
      - operation:
          methods: ["POST"]
          paths: ["*/api"]


Please ensure the remoteIP is populated properly.  More details of this is mentioned in istio documentation
As mentioned in the question if rules section is mentioned twice then in that case only "to" section will get applied.  And istio will allow requests from any ip.
The authorization policy should look like below
  action: ALLOW
  rules:
    - from:
      - source: 
          remoteIpBlocks: [IP address]
      to:
      - operation:
          methods: ["POST"]
          paths: ["*/api"]

